# Distribute boolean logic expression

Tags: python, boolean-logic

What I have :

```
(A.B.C) + (D.E) + (F.G.H.I)
```

What I want using distributive law :

```
(A + D + F).(A + D + G).(A + D + H).(A + D + I).
(A + E + F).(A + E + G).(A + E + H).(A + E + I).
(B + D + F).(B + D + G).(B + D + H).(B + D + I).
(B + E + F).(B + E + G).(B + E + H).(B + E + I).
(C + D + F).(C + D + G).(C + D + H).(C + D + I).
(C + E + F).(C + E + G).(C + E + H).(C + E + I)
```

Both expressions are equivalent. I used distributive law to get the second one : `A + (B . C) ⇔ (A + B) . (A + C)`

The expression can be bigger but is always compose of groups of `AND` separated by `OR`.
What I'm looking for is a library that would be able to distribute logical expressions. A library like [Sympy](http://www.sympy.org/fr/) but applied to logic instead of algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sympy is the perfect choice for this, just take a look to the [logic](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/logic.html) module, in particular, [Equivalent](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/logic.html#sympy.logic.boolalg.Equivalent) and [to_cnf](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/logic.html#sympy.logic.boolalg.to_cnf) functions, example below:

```
from sympy import *

A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I = symbols('A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I')

formula = (
    (A & B & C) | (D & E) | (F & G & H & I)
)
formula2 = (
    (A | D | F) & (A | D | G) & (A | D | H) & (A | D | I) &
    (A | E | F) & (A | E | G) & (A | E | H) & (A | E | I) &
    (B | D | F) & (B | D | G) & (B | D | H) & (B | D | I) &
    (B | E | F) & (B | E | G) & (B | E | H) & (B | E | I) &
    (C | D | F) & (C | D | G) & (C | D | H) & (C | D | I) &
    (C | E | F) & (C | E | G) & (C | E | H) & (C | E | I)
)

print(to_cnf(formula))
print(Equivalent(to_cnf(formula), formula2))
```

Result:

```
(A | D | F) & (A | D | G) & (A | D | H) & (A | D | I) & (A | E | F) & (A | E | G) & (A | E | H) & (A | E | I) & (B | D | F) & (B | D | G) & (B | D | H) & (B | D | I) & (B | E | F) & (B | E | G) & (B | E | H) & (B | E | I) & (C | D | F) & (C | D | G) & (C | D | H) & (C | D | I) & (C | E | F) & (C | E | G) & (C | E | H) & (C | E | I)
True
```

Comment: wow missed all of that ! I did not even know about CNF and DNF, very instructive. In fact what I want is DNF to CNF. Thank you I will we looking the module more in detail.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can do that with the package [boolean.py](https://booleanpy.readthedocs.io) (install it from Pip with `pip install boolean.py`):

```
from boolean import BooleanAlgebra

exp1 = algebra.parse("(A*B*C) + (D*E) + (F*G*H*I)")
# Convert to conjunctive normal form (CNF)
exp2 = algebra.cnf(exp1)
print(exp2.pretty())
```

Output:

```
AND(
  OR(
    Symbol('A'),
    Symbol('D'),
    Symbol('F')
  ),
  OR(
    Symbol('A'),
    Symbol('D'),
    Symbol('G')
  ),
  OR(
    Symbol('A'),
    Symbol('D'),
    Symbol('H')
  ),
  OR(
    Symbol('A'),
    Symbol('D'),
    Symbol('I')
  ),
  OR(
    Symbol('A'),
    Symbol('E'),
    Symbol('F')
  ),
  OR(
    Symbol('A'),
    Symbol('E'),
    Symbol('G')
  ),
  OR(
    Symbol('A'),
    Symbol('E'),
    Symbol('H')
  ),
  OR(
    Symbol('A'),
    Symbol('E'),
    Symbol('I')
  ),
  OR(
    Symbol('B'),
    Symbol('D'),
    Symbol('F')
  ),
  OR(
    Symbol('B'),
    Symbol('D'),
    Symbol('G')
  ),
  OR(
    Symbol('B'),
    Symbol('D'),
    Symbol('H')
  ),
  OR(
    Symbol('B'),
    Symbol('D'),
    Symbol('I')
  ),
  OR(
    Symbol('B'),
    Symbol('E'),
    Symbol('F')
  ),
  OR(
    Symbol('B'),
    Symbol('E'),
    Symbol('G')
  ),
  OR(
    Symbol('B'),
    Symbol('E'),
    Symbol('H')
  ),
  OR(
    Symbol('B'),
    Symbol('E'),
    Symbol('I')
  ),
  OR(
    Symbol('C'),
    Symbol('D'),
    Symbol('F')
  ),
  OR(
    Symbol('C'),
    Symbol('D'),
    Symbol('G')
  ),
  OR(
    Symbol('C'),
    Symbol('D'),
    Symbol('H')
  ),
  OR(
    Symbol('C'),
    Symbol('D'),
    Symbol('I')
  ),
  OR(
    Symbol('C'),
    Symbol('E'),
    Symbol('F')
  ),
  OR(
    Symbol('C'),
    Symbol('E'),
    Symbol('G')
  ),
  OR(
    Symbol('C'),
    Symbol('E'),
    Symbol('H')
  ),
  OR(
    Symbol('C'),
    Symbol('E'),
    Symbol('I')
  )
)
```

Comment: I had to choose an answer to accept. Your answer is also acceptable. I only prefer using Sympy as @BPL suggested. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Dionys Yes, I think the Sympy answer is more useful, since it is a much more common library (I just wasn't aware it implemented Boolean algebra too).